# Rでssh先のファイル名を取得する方法

Tags: r, ssh

```
  >dataname = function()
   {
      system("sshpass -p password ssh IP 'ls -l Dir/*.txt'")
   }

  >dataname()
  filename1.txt
  filename2.txt
```

といった方法で取得したのですが、読み込んだテーブルの列名にdatanameを付け加えることができません。
どうにか取得して、テーブルに名前を付ける方法はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

system()だけではコンソールに結果は出力されますが、データにはなっていないので、intern=TRUEをつけると文字ベクタになりますよ。

```
# filenames列としてファイル一覧を持ったデータフレームを作成
data.frame(filenames=system("ls",intern=TRUE))
```